# Одномерный массив. Программа должна брать из столбца числа и складывать их воедино

Tags: c#

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.RowCount = Convert.ToInt16(numericUpDown1.Value);
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int n = Convert.ToInt16(numericUpDown1.Value);
        double[] a = new double[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            a[i] = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
        }
        double v = a[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            if (a[i] > 0)
            {
                v = v + a[i];
            }
```

При вводе чисел, выходит дичь, например 4+4+5=12, а 4+4+4= 16

Comment: А в чем затруднение?

Comment: При вводе чисел, выходит дичь, например 4+4+5=12, а 4+4+4= 16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Два раза первый элемент берете:

```
double v = a[0];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
```

Comment: даже если так, ответ никак не сходится.

Comment: Так еще раз, чего именно вы хотите добиться?

Comment: Есть столбец, размер которого регулирует пользователь, и не зависимо от количество строк в столбце, он должен брать все числа и складывать, но только положительные.

Comment: Все числа из заданного диапазона 0...n? Верно я понял?

Comment: x>0 , да, правильно.

Comment: Я переписал заново код и нашел ошибку, вы были.double v = a[0];
изменил на 0 и все заработало.